# How do I use play-framework tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, playframework

I'm using the Play Framework to build a Website, that shows some Markers on a Google Map. For that I create and save some Models in the Application.class controller. But when I render these Models i couldn't find out how to get these use these Model-Objects in javascript. Does anyone know, how to use the Play Framework Tags on Javascript?

Comment: Give us some sample, I have no idea what are you asking about

Comment: If you can show us what you have done so far, we can work on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, I wanted to use the "Play-Tags" in my JavaScript-File. For example like this:

```
        #{list items: all, as:'object'}
        addMarkerFromRendered("${object.name}", "${object.lat}", "${object.lng}", "${object.type}", "${object.description}", "/public/img/${object.type}.png");
          #{/list}
```

But the Play Tags are not defined for Javascript so the compiler stops at "${" and throws an error.

To solve the problem I wrote a function in my Javascript file:

```
var addMarkerFromRendered = function(name, lat, lng, category, description, icon){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    addMarker(latLng, name, category,description, icon);
};
```

And then I used the function in my HTML-File to render my data:

```
    <script>
    $('#map').ready(function(){
      #{list items: all, as:'object'}
      addMarkerFromRendered("${object.name}", "${object.lat}", "${object.lng}", "${object.type}", "${object.description}", "/public/img/${object.type}.png");
        #{/list}
      });
  </script>
```